# Selenium not .click giving "object not callable" error

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automate my rental search. I can get the first page of results but when I try to click the next button I get an error - "object not callable" I am new to Python and just thought this would be a fun project to learn with - any help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import re






pages = set()

def getLinks(url):
global pages
# Open web browser and get url - 3 second time delay.
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
pageSource = driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pageSource)
for addr_link in bsObj.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^/homedetails/*")):
    if 'href' in addr_link.attrs:
        if addr_link['href'] not in pages:
            newPage = addr_link.attrs['href']
            pages.add(newPage)
            print(newPage)

#if bsObj.find('li', {'class': "zsg-pagination-next"}) == True:
next_page = bsObj.find('li', {'class': "zsg-pagination-next"}).find("a")
#next_page.click()
print(next_page)
next_page.click()
getLinks(http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/Jackson-County-MO/house,mobile_type/1804_rid/6m_days/39.198737,-93.6866,38.873394,-95.026932_rect/9_zm/)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML, properly formatted.

Comment: http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/Jackson-County-MO/house,mobile_type/1804_rid/6m_days/39.198737,-93.6866,38.873394,-95.026932_rect/9_zm/

Comment: Please add the link to the original question so people are more likely to see it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve above task, you don't need beautifulsoup, it can be done with webdriver. Try below code.

```
//Code to Fetch All the Link Details Through WebDriver

addr_link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'homedetails')]")
for link in addr_link : 
print link.get_attribute("href")


//Code To Click On Next Button
next_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Next']")
next_btn.click()
```

Comment: I still receive a No attribute to click message - also I am using BeatifulSoup because I need that to get the rent amount and contact manager phone number on the page of the rental listing

Comment: Please share script code and error message detail, i'll take a look.

Comment: Not to sound like an idiot - but what do you mean, the script code is in the questions unless you mean something else. when changed to your suggestion I get 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: yes, click is not attribute, it's a method. so use it like 
    'link.click()'

Comment: ok but I used your exact code next_btn.click() is that not correct?

Comment: Hmm, Due to next button is not in view port. It might be throwing error. Try below code to click on next button instead of normal click. 

**driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_btn)**

Comment: Yea that didn't do it either